# Start activity after crash in android

Tags: android

I have a question: which activity is running when application crash? First from stack? This is any way to catch that and start activity which I want after crash? Maybe is any way to start activity after crash on my own way.

Comment: I think you are looking for [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16562770/2345913)!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Android ANR** dialog is a System Handled (Generated) you don't have a any control over it..

As its implemented in System OS Source So you can't change the ANR Dialog. As you can't catch when ANR comes.

The only option is modifying the Android OS Source.

Answer (score -3):

try launching and intent from a try and catch loop.if your code fails in the try block the intent from the catch block should be launched automatically.

```
try{
   //faulty code here.
  }catch(Exception e){
   Intent i=new Intent(currentactivity.this,yournextactivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   }
```

Comment: Android ANR dialog is a System Handled (Generated) you don't have a any control over it and can't catch when ANR comes.