# How to send android app logs to remote server?

Tags: java, android, exception

In my application, I want to send logs in case of crash to remote server. I have added try-catch block and in catch I'm sending logs to server. I want to know what all exceptions should I catch. I need logs in case of every crash so that I can fix it.  Would it be a good practice to catch all Exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a summarized list of suggestions I curated from other great answers:

- **Catch all unhandled exceptions**.

  1. Create an `ExceptionHandler` that implements `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`. You can use this class to customize and log errors.
  2. Put this: `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler(this));` inside `OnCreate()` method (after `super()`) of each of your `Activity` class .
  3. For details, please refer to this great answer from [Android exception handling best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561692/android-exception-handling-best-practice) .
- **Enclose try/catch around all codes that run externally/from outside. (e.g - codes using 3rd party components)**
- **Enclose try/catch around all codes that you know, can fail on certain conditions**

  1. When there is no internet connections
  2. During I/O Operations
  3. When there is potential for crazy user inputs
  4. When there is potential for divide by zero situations
- **Use try/catch at the top level** because all exceptions are bubbled up to the top level. So, in inner functions, if need be, you can consider using `throw` exception. Then, at the top level, **catch specific exceptions** and **sort your exception types** in catch block correctly. (Referred from this great answer: [How using try catch for exception handling is best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice)
- For UI, you should offer "continued usability" by providing "limited functionality" version of the app even if the error occurs (if the error is due to, for example, no internet connectivity).
- Over-eager error reporting to user is not a good idea.
- Persistent error messages are bad. Inform user with a message and let the user close/remove it.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice) | [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561692/android-exception-handling-best-practice) | [Reference 3](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/java-exception-handling-tutorial-with-examples-and-best-practices.html) | [Further Reading 1](http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/10_best_practices_with_Exceptions) | [Further Reading 2](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html) | [Further Reading 3](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/)

---

For an Android library to remotely log unhandled exceptions, you can take a look at this: [android-remote-stacktrace](https://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/) .

- Download [.jar](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/downloads/list) file.
- Add it to Java Build path.
- Add INTERNET permission: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
- In the `OnCreate` method of your activity or service, put 'ExceptionHandler.register(this, "http://your.domain/path");'
- On your server, place [this PHP file](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/source/browse/server/collect/server.php), which you can edit to extend the functionality.

Comment: Server part is not handled by me. Is there any default server where I can post?

Comment: The default goes to http://trace.nullwire.com. Or you can use a free PHP web host to test out the feature.

Comment: I want to send logs to the same server where I'm storing data. And I have API for that where I have to send many other parameters with the exception. So my question is what all exceptions should I catch.

Comment: i updated my answer to try to reflect your question about when and which exceptions you should catch. please have a look. if the answer helped, please mark as answer and upvote!

Comment: `nullwire.com` seems dead now

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Crashlytics or Bugsense**

https://mint.splunk.com/

https://try.crashlytics.com/

Comment: I dont have to use 3rd party libs