# "global" exception handling & activity lifecycle

Tags: java, android, api, exception, activity-lifecycle

Image the following scenario:

I've got an Android application which talks to an `API` across multiple activities. I'm using a self-written "`Authenticator`" class to ensure that I always have a valid session. But it's nevertheless possible, that the authentication fails.

**Now to my question**:
Is there a slick way to handle an "`UnauthenticatedException`" my Authenticator may throw by forwarding to an `LoginActivity` without having to write the same try-catch in every API-talking activity and without making the Authenticator context-aware?

Comment: Just use a `Interface` i guess you are already using one to forward the `Exception` to calling component .

Comment: This seems interesting...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561692/android-exception-handling-best-practice

Comment: This question seems nice, but what i do is to implement a class in my Aplication file that is aware of the lifecycle and nows everthing about the state of the app. I guest that is not what you want.